# Get value of clicked nested element with element.bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the following code in my directive and it always seems like the click is not able to keep track of my $location.$$path very well. This plug-in I am using is also using the `<li></li>` as a clickable item with a path which may be causing the issue. So my question would be if there a way I can skit the out elements and just focus down on the `<a href="#myValue>` which is a child of that `<li>`?

```
.directive('treeClick', function ($location) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.bind("mousedown", function () {
            console.log($location.$$path);
          })
        }
    }
  })

<li class="list-group-item node-tree node-selected" data-nodeid="2" style="color:#000;background-color:#eaeaea;"><span class="indent"></span><span class="indent"></span><span class="icon glyphicon"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span><a href="#myValue" style="color:inherit;">Example1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that for what you're trying to do, you're using the wrong event.  What if you tried `mouseup` instead of `mousedown` (you might also need to `$timeout` your processing if the update to the url is asynchronous, but I'm thinking it's not)?

Couple more things..  Angular exposes an event for when the location changes named `$locationChangeSuccess`

And..  `$$path` is an internal property, why not use the documented `$location.path()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Thank you for the .path() and mouseup but I am still having the same issue of me having to click the `li` twice before it actually console.logs out the correct value.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the log in a timeout, for example `$timeout(function(){ console.log($location.path()) }, 100, false);`

Comment: I ended up doing `event.target.nodeName` and ran the route if `event.target.nodeName === "A"` I think the multiple elements clicks in the html was confusing the `console.log($location.path())` This was cleanup I needed to do anyways because the `<li>` obviously are not wrapped in `<a>`

Comment: do you have the `treeClick` directive on the `a` element?

Comment: Treeclick is an attribute on the `div id="tree"` I just pass in a json object and the plug-in generates the rest which is ul > li > a. I got it work using my above comment. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.nodeName` gave me what the element was: "A" for anchor "LI" for list item. I then extracted the value of the "A" by using `event.target.nodeName.getAttribute("href");` so that I do not get the host name in the console.log()